# RandomInstance of GeometricScene producing unexpected result

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, synthetic-geometry

Consider the following scene as an example:

```
scene=GeometricScene[{
    {"B","P","N","T"},{}
},{
    lH==Line[{"B","P"}],
    lV==Line[{"B","N"}],
    GeometricAssertion[lH,"Horizontal","Leftward"],
    GeometricAssertion[lV,"Vertical","Upward"],
    GeometricAssertion[{{"P"},{"T"}},{"OppositeSides",lV}],
    PlanarAngle[{"T","B","N"},"Counterclockwise"]==12\[Degree],
    EuclideanDistance["B","T"]==20,
    EuclideanDistance["T","P"]==35
}];

instance=RandomInstance[scene,RandomSeeding->0]
```

Gives an incorrect scene.

```
{PlanarAngle[{"P","B","N"}],PlanarAngle[{"P","B","T"}]}/\[Degree]/.instance["Points"]
```

Produces:

> {161.143, 180.}

This is wrong, the expected answer was:

> {90., 102.}

[image]

---

Also look at the following scene:

```
scene=GeometricScene[{
    {"NA","NB","NF","A","B","F"},{}
},{
    lA==Line[{"A","NA"}],
    lB==Line[{"B","NB"}],
    lF==Line[{"F","NF"}],
    GeometricAssertion[{lA,lB,lF},"Vertical","Upward"],
    GeometricAssertion[{{lA},{lB}},{"OppositeSides",lF}],
    PlanarAngle[{"NA","A","B"},"Clockwise"]==70\[Degree],
    PlanarAngle[{"NA","A","F"},"Clockwise"]==25\[Degree],
    PlanarAngle[{"NB","B","F"},"Clockwise"]==345\[Degree],
    EuclideanDistance["A","B"]==20.3,
    EuclideanDistance["A","NA"]==10,
    EuclideanDistance["B","NB"]==10,
    EuclideanDistance["F","NF"]==10
}];
instance=RandomInstance[scene,RandomSeeding->0]
{
    EuclideanDistance["A","F"],
    EuclideanDistance["B","F"]
}/.instance["Points"]//N
```

> {13.6685, 6.78483}

In this scene, the `GeometricAssertion` on the lines being `Upward` aligned is ignored by the system. Also `EuclideanDistance["A","NA"]` is taken to be nearly zero even though I explicitly told it to make it 10.

The correct answer is:

> {31.461, 22.3313}

Comment: Can't reproduce it. The above code produces `{90., 102.}` in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: With `12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)` I get `{161.145, 180.}`

Comment: @user64494 are you using `Wolfram Desktop` or `Mathematica`? check your release id for the kernel, there are multiple 12.2 versions. Run `SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"]`

Comment: @user13892 - what do you get for `EuclideanDistance["B", "N"] /. instance["Points"]`?  I get basically zero.  What if you add the constraint `EuclideanDistance["B", "N"] > 1` to your scene?

Comment: @JasonB. Yes it is nearly zero and adding the constraint `EuclideanDistance["B", "N"] > 1` does fix the issue. Look at the next example where `EuclideanDistance["A","NA"]` is ignored.

Comment: @user13892: `"12.2.0.0 (7198852, 202012124868)"`